# How to create a flag using linear-gradient?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

```css
div{
   height: 500px;
   width: 900px;

   background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,green 33% 66%,yellow 66% 100%,black 111% 222%,yellow 0% 5%,blue 0% 10%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

here's how its supposed to be:

[image: 1]

Comment: and what do you get instead? it's unclear what your question is.

Comment: @underscore_d the picture on the link

Comment: then why did you caption that "here's how its supposed to be", if that's **not** how it's supposed to be..?

Answer (score 1):

Do it with multiple background and it will be easier to handle:

```css
.box {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,#21b539 calc(50% - 40px),#f5cf22 0 calc(50% - 30px),#0000 0),
    linear-gradient(to top    left ,#00a6e0 calc(50% - 40px),#f5cf22 0 calc(50% - 30px),#0000 0)
    #000
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man I really appreciate it Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

try this `background: linear-gradient( to bottom right, green 33% 40%, yellow 40% 45%, black 45% 55%, yellow 55% 60%, blue 60% 100% );`
Also add a height and width to your div

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,green 35%,yellow 35% 40%, black 40% 60%, yellow 60% 65%, dodgerblue 65%);
```

Remember the gradient is in the direction top left to bottom right. And a percentage more than 100 don't make any sense.

```css
div {
  width: 900px;
  height: 500px;
   background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,green 35%,yellow 35% 40%, black 40% 60%, yellow 60% 65%, dodgerblue 65%);
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```